# Calculating harmonics of a signal

Tags: signal-processing

I have signal in vector form containing a number of samples and has frequency w0. I want to find harmonics of that signal. Is there a way to do so?

Let's assume k = 2, for 2*w0, how can i construct harmonic of the signal from samples?
Here first 20 of my samples:

-0.239570299386578
 0.1034882656331065
 0.434308908352916
 0.7137668996246224
 0.9088106936857204
 0.9963988158818323
 0.9661854915005951
 0.8217108676412244
 0.5800958281197547
 0.2698446607867672
 -0.07226783043916135
 -0.4058656575212867
 -0.6914578691976684
 -0.8952909939878536
 -0.9932554094058046
 -0.9737846003601184
 -0.8391674550614948
 -0.6053346354564043
 -0.2999053926206244
 0.04098635822626423

it's period = 18. I want to find the amplitute's of the signal with period 9 by using this values..

if my signal is x[n] and its harmonic is h[n], can i say that h[n] = x[2n]?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an amplitude for any frequency or period by using the Goertzel algorithm.